# different problems with ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, sound

I have been using ubuntu 14.04 LTS for nearly 3 years, suddenly nowadays

1.my system volume(while hearing songs in Rhythom box) automatically changes from mute to normal and vice versa rapidly for every second of time, then this stops after some time and normally plays the audio after clicking for some number of times on the volume icon on top system bar

2.The screen shot application automatically takes screen shot and I was not able to close the screen shot  application

3.few buttons in my keyboard does not work properly for some time then they come back again

this is what had been happening in my computer for the past 3 days it seems like there is ghost inside my computer(just for fun)

I am a computer science student so i have installed IDEs like android studio eclipse, python2.7, python 3.4 ,pycharm,xampp

configuration
         4 gb ram
        asus motherboard 64 bit

Comment: Anything particular you chnged to your system recently?

Comment: No i didn't change anythingi changed from intel core 13 to asus one and  a half year back

Comment: Can you try with a different keyboard?

Comment: i will try i dont have another